# How can one determine the type of a variable in opa?

Tags: types, functional-programming, opa

I' learning the Opa ([opalang.org](http://www.opalang.org)). I am trying to find out how one can determine the type of a variable. This could be e.g. a function

```
typeof a // in javascript, this returns the type of a
```

The API-Documentation contains a [description](http://doc.opalang.org/value/stdlib.core/OpaValue/typeof) of OpaValue.typeof(a) but I can't find out how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example :

```
int hello = 42
hello_type = OpaValue.typeof(hello)
Log.info("Hello type:", "{hello_type}")
```

However i am surprised you want to manipulate Opa types. What is your usage ?

Comment: I use to fiddle around with a language which is new to me and sometimes it is useful to know the type of some thing. In this case I had the line

    match (HttpRequest.get_method()) {
    case {some: method}: 
etc (from http://doc.opalang.org/manual/Hello--web-services)

and wanted to find out what 

    some: method

means. (especially the some:)

Comment: @JanD, `{some: method}` is Opa's syntax for pattern that matches record with one field called `some` and binds the value associated that field to variable called `method`. For instance: `match ({some: 1}) { case {some: x}: x }` should evaluate to 1. Hopefully the example is OK syntactically.